# How to configure custom keyboard shortcuts in ElementaryOS Freya?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, elementaryos

How do you actually set what the keys do???

http://blog.elementary.io/post/119612714681/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-are-here

When I go to this screen I:

- press the + button
- enter the name of the shortcut ('my cool shortcut')
- press the sequence of keys
- and... that's where it ends. Where's the part where I define the actual action the shortcut keys will do?

I want to press Ctrl+Shift+T in a zshell terminal and duplicate the current tab that I'm in.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate", exactly? Just the same working directory, the same history or actually the same content?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the same working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't at all obvious, but where you're entering 'my cool shortcut' is not actually a name field. That field expects the path to the executable, e.g. /usr/bin/galculator.